# Ideas on implementing graph in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need help to design the best data structure for a GRAPH. The following is my implementation.
Please give your thoughts on this design.

```
#ifndef _GRAPH_H_
#define _GRAPH_H_

#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template <typename T>
class Vertex {
public:
      Vertex(){};
      Vertex(T inVertex): m_vertex(inVertex), m_visited(false){}
      ~Vertex(){}
      bool operator<(const Vertex<T>& right) const { return m_vertex < right.m_vertex;}

      T getVertex  () { return m_vertex;}
      T getVisited () { return m_visited;}
      T getParent  () { return m_vertexParentVisited;}
      void setVisited(bool inVisited)  { m_visited = inVisited;}
      void setParent(T inParentVertex) { m_vertexParentVisited = inParentVertex;}

private:
      T m_vertex;
      T m_vertexParentVisited;
      bool m_visited;
};

template <typename T>
class Edge
{
public:
    enum EDGE_TYPE
    {
        TREE_EDGE,
        PARENT_EDGE,
        BACK_EDGE,
        DOWN_EDGE
    };
    Edge(Vertex<T>* inSrc, Vertex<T>* inDst)
    {
        m_SourceVertex = inSrc;
        m_DestVertex   = inDst;
    }
    void SetEdgeType( EDGE_TYPE t)
    {
        m_EdgeType = t;
    }
private:
    Vertex<T>* m_SourceVertex;
    Vertex<T>* m_DestVertex;
    EDGE_TYPE  m_EdgeType;
protected:
};

template <typename T>
class Graph
{
public:
      typedef Vertex<T>                             GraphVertex;
      // Adjancency List Datastructure and Iterator declaration.
      // Use STL List here
      typedef std::list<GraphVertex*>               AdjList;
      typedef typename AdjList::iterator            AdjListIterator;
      // Graph Data structure declaration and Iterator declaration
      // Graph is map of GraphVertex* and List of adjacency list.
      typedef std::map<GraphVertex*, AdjList>       GraphMap;
      typedef typename GraphMap::iterator           GraphIterator;
      // Graph Memory pool is map where actual memory allocation 
      // will happen.
      // Make sure you have some way to identify each vertex.
      // Map key is the identification method of the vertex.
      // Map value is the pointer to actual object.
      typedef std::map<T,GraphVertex*>              GraphMemoryPool;
      typedef typename GraphMemoryPool::iterator    GraphInMemoryIterator;
      // Edge Class Declaration.
      typedef std::vector<Edge<T> >                 GraphEdge;

private:          
      bool               m_isDirected;
      GraphMap           m_graph;
      GraphMemoryPool    m_graphMemoryPool;
      std::vector<T>     m_SearchOrderVector;
      GraphEdge          m_GraphEdge;
public:
      Graph(bool inIsDirected):m_isDirected(inIsDirected) {}
      ~Graph()
      {
            for ( GraphInMemoryIterator itr = m_graphMemoryPool.begin(); itr != m_graphMemoryPool.end(); ++itr)
            {
                  if ( itr->second) delete itr->second;
            }
            m_graphMemoryPool.clear();
            m_graph.clear();
      }
      void insert(T inSRC, T inDST) 
      {
            if ( m_isDirected) 
            {
                  __insert(inSRC,inDST);
            }
            else 
            {
                  __insert(inSRC,inDST);
                  __insert(inDST,inSRC);
            }
      }
      void printGraph()
      {
            for ( GraphIterator itr = m_graph.begin(); itr != m_graph.end(); ++itr) 
            {
                  std::cout << static_cast<GraphVertex*>(itr->first)->getVertex() << " : ";
                  AdjList tmp = static_cast<AdjList>(itr->second);
                  for ( AdjListIterator itr1 = tmp.begin(); itr1 != tmp.end(); ++itr1) 
                  {
                        std::cout << (*itr1)->getVertex() << " ";
                  }
                  std::cout << std::endl;
            }
      }
      void printSearchOrder()
      {
            std::vector<T> tmp = getSearchOrderVector();
            for ( vector<T>::iterator itr = tmp.begin(); itr != tmp.end(); ++itr)
            {
                std::cout << *itr << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;

      }
      void printParentLinkMap()
      {
          std::vector<T> tmp = getSearchOrderVector();
          for ( vector<T>::iterator itr = tmp.begin(); itr != tmp.end(); ++itr)
          {
                GraphVertex *tmp = __VertexInstance(*itr);
                std::cout << "[" << tmp->getParent() << "]  Parent Of [" << tmp->getVertex() << "]" << std::endl;
          }
      }
      void DFS()
      {
            for ( GraphInMemoryIterator itr = m_graphMemoryPool.begin(); itr != m_graphMemoryPool.end(); ++itr)
            {
                  (*itr).second->setVisited(false);
            }
            m_SearchOrderVector.clear();
            // This loop handles the case when the grpah is not
            // Connected.
            for ( GraphIterator itr = m_graph.begin(); itr != m_graph.end(); ++itr) 
            {
                GraphVertex *currentVertex = static_cast<GraphVertex*>(itr->first);
                if ( currentVertex->getVisited() == false) 
                {
                    T curVertex = currentVertex->getVertex();
                    // Insert new element in Search Order Vector.
                    m_SearchOrderVector.push_back(curVertex);
                    // Set the parent of this root node in the DFS search tree
                    currentVertex->setParent(curVertex);
                    // Create Edge with itself here.
                    __setTypeAndInsertNewEdge( curVertex, 
                                               curVertex,
                                               Edge<T>::TREE_EDGE);
                    // Mark the vertex as visited.
                    currentVertex->setVisited(true);
                    __rundfs(itr);
                }
            }
      }
    std::vector<T> getSearchOrderVector() { return m_SearchOrderVector;}
    int getNumberOfVertex(){ return (int)m_graph.size();}
private:
    void __setTypeAndInsertNewEdge( T inSRC, T inDST, typename Edge<T>::EDGE_TYPE t )
    {
        Edge<T> tmp(__VertexInstance(inSRC), 
                    __VertexInstance(inDST));
        tmp.SetEdgeType(t);
        m_GraphEdge.push_back(tmp);
    }
    // Recursive DFS function.
    // Apart from visiting vertices 
    // this implementatioin will be doing following.
    // 1. Maintain the order in which vertices are visited.   
    // 2. Update Parent link map
    // 3. Create Edge and update the type of the edge.
    void __rundfs( typename GraphMap::iterator &itr) 
    {
        for (AdjListIterator itr1 = itr->second.begin(); itr1 != itr->second.end(); ++itr1) 
        {
            GraphVertex *childVertex = (*itr1);
            GraphVertex *parentVertex = itr->first;
            if ( childVertex->getVisited() == false) 
            {
                m_SearchOrderVector.push_back(childVertex->getVertex()); // Update the search order Vector.
                childVertex->setParent(parentVertex->getVertex());         // Update the parent-link map.
                childVertex->setVisited(true);                           // Mark the vertex as visited.
                __setTypeAndInsertNewEdge(parentVertex->getVertex(),
                                          childVertex->getVertex(),
                                          Edge<T>::TREE_EDGE); // setup the edge type 
                __rundfs(m_graph.find(
                        __VertexInstance(childVertex->getVertex())));
            }     
            else
            {
                if ( childVertex->getVertex() == parentVertex->getVertex())
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void __insert(T inSRC, T inDST) 
    {
        GraphIterator itr = m_graph.find(__VertexInstance(inSRC));
        if ( itr != m_graph.end()) 
        {
            // Update the Adjancency list 
            itr->second.push_back(__VertexInstance(inDST));
        }
        else 
        {
            // Create new Adjancy list
            m_graph.insert(std::make_pair(__VertexInstance(inSRC),AdjList() ));
            GraphIterator itr = m_graph.find(__VertexInstance(inSRC));
            // Update the Adjacency List
            itr->second.push_back(__VertexInstance(inDST));
        }
    }
    // Searches if the Vertex is already allocated in the pool map
    // If ye return the pointer from the map.
    // Else Create new Vertex instance
    // Insert into the memory pool map
    // Return the pointer.
    GraphVertex *__VertexInstance(T inVertex) 
    {
        GraphVertex *newVertex    = (GraphVertex *)0;
        GraphInMemoryIterator itr = m_graphMemoryPool.find(inVertex);
        if ( itr == m_graphMemoryPool.end()) 
        {
            newVertex = new GraphVertex(inVertex);
            m_graphMemoryPool.insert(std::make_pair(inVertex,newVertex));
        }
        else 
        {
            newVertex = ( GraphVertex *)itr->second;
        }           
        return newVertex;
    }
};
#endif
```

Comment: why not use existing implementation?

Comment: I agree with you it is better option to use existing implementation, But I am writing my own since I am studying graph also

Comment: in that case, you probably need to return references rather than values and have constant functions as well.  you seem to be using pointers, references will probably be better.  do not use variables starting with __, those are reserved for implementations

Comment: How big is your graph?  A 2D array of edge weights makes a really nice and simple implementation.  A 1D array of linked lists of edge weights is also clean and can scale to very large graphs.

Comment: To provide a more useful answer, it would be helpful if you could explain how the current standard implementations fail to meet your needs.

Comment: can you please explain enum EDGE_TYPE? I don't get it's purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you know this, but I'm reviewing for all to benefit:

There are two typical ways to implement a graph: a matrix of edges, and a sparse matrix (represented as a vector of edges for each vertex).

The matrix is an NxN structure where N is the number of vertices. Each datum is the edge length between the two vertices, so G[1][2] is the distance from 1 to 2. This also allow for directed graphs.

The other method, better for sparse graphs, is to have a vector of edges for each vertex. So you'd have vector> g where g[1] is the vector of edges for vertex 1. Each item in that vector would be and edge holding the vertex it goes to and the distance.

For more details go here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(data_structure)#Representations

Given all that, one of these implementations is likely to be quite useful to you.

**EDIT1**

For storing weights in a graph, on might use a structure such as vector> (as noted above). In such a case, the edge class may be like this:

```
class edge {
  int weight;
  int destination_vertex;
};
```

In this way, the edge from 1 to 2 would be g[1][2].

Comment: Thanks JoshD, This helps, but I am confuse on how to extend this design of graph further, with your explanation my graph will be Vector of VERTICES and I can have separte VERTEX class to store information about VERTICES, but what about EDGES, how should I store WEIGHT of EDGES further

Comment: I was thinking to have VERTEX class as a ABC , so that my team members can implement this Interface and use driver GRAPH class

Comment: You have a vector that is subscripted by the VERTEX index, but that vector returns a map (in the sparse case) that you subscript with another vertex:  weight = graph[from][to];

Comment: To store weights in an adjacency list, the VERTEX class can simply have a weight. I'll update my answer.

Comment: If you like STL, you could do the whole thing like:  typedef vector<map<double> > graph;

Comment: Excellent suggestions, xscott. I've added them to the answer.

Comment: One cautionary note, though. If no edge exists between 1 and 2, the call to g[1][2] will create a default one. Just be sure to use the find function to check if an edge exists.

Comment: @xscott I think you meant `typedef vector<map<int,double>> graph;` Nice suggestion.

Comment: It's never too late. @Avinash, stop shouting.